# Cake Bakery path not working in OS X 10.9.2

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, osx-mavericks

I want to do "cake bake" command in terminal. So, I added the following path to my profile.

Step 1 : `sudo nano ~/.profile`

Step 2 : `export PATH=/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/php-5.5.6;/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql;/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sandbox/app/Console/cake;`

I added this path and tried to "cake bake" command in terminal. But, the terminal is absolutely not working. When I open new terminal window, it results the following.

```
Last login: Fri May 16 00:45:42 on ttys000
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1090
Server version: 5.6.14 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I want to do "cake bake" in my Mac. Please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: I also tried to added path to my cakephp folder in ".profile"
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sandbox/app/Console/cake;
But, this path also not working. Can't use "cake bake" command in terminal. 
I want to know what is the correct path in order to do "cake bake" command.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Don't do that

The only steps required to use the CakePHP cli are:

```
$ cd path/to/App
$ Console/cake 

Welcome to CakePHP v3.0.0-dev2 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : App
Path: /path/to/App/
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

While the Console folder can be added to the path, it's not required and not recommended.

### What's wrong

A terminal should look similar to this:

[image: a blank, new osx window]

But there are **executable files** defined *as* the path instead of *in* the path.

```
export PATH=.../bin/mysql;.../app/Console/cake
                    ^                      ^
```

Because of that when a new terminal windows is started, the mysql executable is being immediately invoked starting an interactive mysql session as should be evident by the output:

```
...
mysql>
```

That's why it's not possible to use CakePHP's cli (or basically anything), *because it's not an sql command*:

```
mysql> cake
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cake' at line 1
mysql>
```

To get out of that, type "exit" which will then hopefully get back to a bash prompt where the `.profile` file can be edited appropriately.

```
mysql> exit
Bye
$
```

There may well be further mess/confusing output in the terminal window, if it's not possible to edit the `.profile` file via a terminal window close all terminal windows, delete the file `~/.profile` by any means and then when a new terminal is started it should work fine again.

To correct the path - ensure it contains *directories* and not *files*:

```
export PATH=.../Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin
                                              ^ a directory
```